# How to get the values of temperature from FLIR AX8 Camera using Modbus TCP/IP

Tags: modbus-tcp, flir

I am trying to get the values of the temperature from [FLIR AX8 camera](https://www.flir.com/products/ax8-automation/) using Modbus TCP/IP. In the [document](https://flir.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/22238/0/filename/EtherNetIP+and+ModBus+TCP+Object+Models+%28FLIR+Systems+Object+Model+version+1.21%29.pdf) (page 67) I can see that the temperature register is 1019-1020. But when I try to query this register, I get no response. Below is the transmission:

```
Holding register: 1019
Slave ID: 109
IP : 169.254.80.21

TX-> 00 00 00 00 00 06 6d 03 03 fb 00 01
RX-> 00 00 00 00 00 03 6d 83 02
```

Has anyone worked previously with this camera communication. Can anyone please help me getting the temperature values from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I've connected to the camera and was able to read registers.
What tooling/utility are you trying to use?
I find the Simply Modbus TCP Client (8.1.1 in my case) very good to use.
It will validate if you can create a connection and normally you need to reference a Modbus TCP register with something like: 41019 (that's what the line in the top of the manual 'Register 40XXXX' is trying to tell you)
Did you try address 41019 in your case (and then read two registers as you also need 41020?)?